# Running a bat script with invoke-command works on vm:s but not on physical machines

Tags: invoke-command

I try to run an oracle bat script (opatch.bat) remotely to gather info on patchlevels on oracle agent installations.
The command to run is

```
invoke-command -ComputerName <remote_computer> -scriptblock { D:\oracle\product\eeagent\agent_13.4.0..0\OPatch\opatch.bat lsinventory }
```

It works flawlessly on virtual machines (producing the expected output) but on physical nodes I get:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The syntax of the command is incorrect.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : <remote computer>
```

It seems to be related to running the opatch.bat script specificaly - replacing the scriptblock with for example

```
{ dir D:\oracle\product\eeagent\agent_13.4.0..0\OPatch\ }
```

works as expected.
I have also tried running it this way:

```
invoke-command -computername <remote computer> -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'D:\oracle\product\eeagent\agent_13.4.0.0.0\OPatch\opatch.bat lsinventory'"}
```

But the result it the same.
The physical node and vm are identical as to windows patchlevel and Oracle installation.

I'm intrigued by what is happening here. Any suggestions on what it could be and how to troubleshoot it?
I guess I either am missing something obvious, or there is some down-in-the-weeds serialization issue.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few reasons why running a batch script with Invoke-Command works on virtual machines (VMs) but not on physical machines:

```
Security settings: Physical machines may have more restrictive security settings in place that prevent remote execution of scripts. Check that the Windows Remote Management (WinRM) service is running on the physical machines and that the firewall is configured to allow remote access.

User permissions: The user account running the Invoke-Command command may not have sufficient permissions to execute the batch script on the physical machines. Make sure the user account has administrative privileges on the target machines.

Execution policy: The execution policy on the physical machines may be set to restrict the execution of scripts. To check the current execution policy, run the following command in PowerShell: Get-ExecutionPolicy. If it's set to Restricted, change it to RemoteSigned or Unrestricted using the Set-ExecutionPolicy command.

Antivirus or security software: Antivirus or security software on the physical machines may be blocking the execution of the batch script. Check that any security software on the physical machines is configured to allow remote execution of scripts.
```

It's also worth noting that there can be differences in the configuration of VMs and physical machines that could affect the ability to run scripts remotely. For example, VMs may have more permissive firewall rules or be configured with different security settings than physical machines.

Comment: Since it works for other commands, it is not a WinRM issue. The account has the same group and user privs on all the servers involved. Running the command locally logged on as the same user works., Exceution policy and security / antivirus is handled with GPO:s / by policy and these machines are identical in this matter.